# Accidentally delete /tmp in Weblogic 12c, does it affect the application?

Tags: weblogic, tmp

I accidentally delete /tmp in Weblogic 12c, does it affect the application performance or functionality?

Comment: Contents shouldn't matter, but you need to add the folder back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the server tmp directories (ie. $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/SERVERNAME/tmp) then yes, you could run into errors, but these should be solved by restarting that WebLogic instance.

So if possible, restart at an oppertune moment.